# Acessing chart data in a Picture Type Inline object

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm currently working on a simple word macro that reads data from an excel spreadsheet and inserts it into specified places in multiple word documents.

Apart from placing the data as text the macro also inserts data into existing charts in the Word template.

To do this im using the InlineShapes object like such:

```
ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(6).Chart.ChartData.Activate
ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(6).Chart.ChartData.Workbook.Worksheets(1).Range("B2").Value = uwp
ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(6).Chart.ChartData.Workbook.Worksheets(1).Range("C2").Value = uwpsamo
ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(6).Chart.ChartData.Workbook.Worksheets(1).Range("D2").Value = uwpprze
ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(6).Chart.ChartData.Workbook.Worksheets(1).Range("E2").Value = uwprown
ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(6).Chart.ChartData.Workbook.Worksheets(1).Range("F2").Value = uwppodw
ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(6).Chart.ChartData.Workbook.Close
```

This works fine with one excepton

There is a total of 18 inline objects in my word document, first is of type 3 (picture), after that 16 are of type 12 (chart) and the last one is of type 3 (picture again). The last one is the problem. On top of that picture exists another chart which is not in ActiveDocument.InlineShapes collection

[image]

Any idea how to access the chart data in the last inline shape?
InlineShapes.Chart does not work for the last one as the picture type does not have a chart object.

Comment: I'm not really clear on what this last object is. On the one hand you say "On top of that picture exists another chart" and then you say "the last one as the picture type does not have a chart object". Is the chart "on top" of the picture? Or is it in a Drawing Canvas? Or is it a static picture? You might try querying Word with `ActiveDocument.Shapes.Count`. If, as you say, it's "on top of the picture" then it would be a `Shape`, not an `InlineShape`.

Comment: Thank you Cindy, reffering to the objet using Shapes solved the problem

Comment: Glad it helped :-) FWIW you could make your code more effiicient by not repeating the entire hierarchy `ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(6).Chart.ChartData` in every line. Try, for example: `Dim cd as ChartData : Set cd= ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(6).Chart.ChartData` and then you can use `cd.Activate`, etc.